# In Powershell, how can I prevent my insert key status from turning to "overwrite" every time I run a command?

Tags: windows, powershell

First off, I know this is not default behavior.  In fact, I've never seen anything like this happen and I'm a long time Powershell user.

I have no problems with the `Insert` key in any other application.  However, in Powershell, its initial state is off, or "overwrite" - which is barely if every used anymore.  When I press `Insert` to turn it on and run a command, it then turns back off.

This has become overwhelmingly frustrating as I frequently press `Up Arrow` to go to the previous command to edit it, and find that it's in overwrite mode and it really messes me up.

I googled and found nothing, so I decided screw it, I'm getting a new work PC soon anyhow, so I'll just get in the habit of hitting `Insert` every time I press `Enter`.  Works fine - until I switch PCs and now at home I've been hitting `Insert` by habit and driving myself nuts.

This behavior happens in all Powershell windows - 64-bit, inside VSCode, etc.

Comment: I think this has to do with VSCode, not PowerShell. I found [this article](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=adammaras.overtype) about it.

Comment: have you tried replacing the keyboard? that really sounds like a keypress glitch in the keyboard ...

Comment: Have you checked you `PSReadLine` configuration?

Comment: You'll probably want to go to the PowerShell properties to make sure that the `Insert Mode` is checked (set on) at the _Options_ tab. (There could be more PowerShell shortcuts).

Comment: @JosefZ You should add that as an answer.  It's correct and I'd rather you get the credit!

Answer (score 1):

[*On demand*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53563051/in-powershell-how-can-i-prevent-my-insert-key-status-from-turning-to-overwrite?noredirect=1#comment94060516_53563051) answer:

1. Check the `InsertMode` value in `HKCU\Console` registry key (and all subkeys). If present, then the value should be `1` for most *console prompt*-like programs, e.g. as follows (output truncated for brief: removed *Ubuntu* and multiple *Command Prompt*):

```
^^> reg query HKCU\Console /V InsertMode /S

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console
    InsertMode    REG_DWORD    0x1

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\Command Prompt
    InsertMode    REG_DWORD    0x1

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\powershell
    InsertMode    REG_DWORD    0x1

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\Windows PowerShell
    InsertMode    REG_DWORD    0x1

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\Windows PowerShell (x86)
    InsertMode    REG_DWORD    0x1

End of search: 9 match(es) found.
```

2. You'll probably want to go to the *PowerShell* properties to make sure that the `Insert Mode` is checked (set on) at the *Options* tab.

[image: PowerShell Properties]

`%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows PowerShell\` folder seems to be the right place where the `Windows PowerShell.lnk` shortcut is used to be saved. However, there could be more PowerShell shortcuts. Check

```
where.exe /R "%USERPROFILE%" *Powershell*.lnk|findstr /V /C:"Shell ISE"
```

or even (run from an *elevated* command prompt)

```
2>NUL where.exe /R C:\ *Powershell*.lnk|findstr /V /C:"Shell ISE"
```